# Cpp expression does not get executed

Tags: c++, string, variables, char

I have created a simple function that gets a string called `code` and reads it line by line (The line seperator is defined as TERMINATOR, and currently is `'\n'`). So I wrote this mess:

```
uint16_t* compile(string code){
    for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++){
        string line;
        
        while(code[i] != TERMINATOR){
            char c = code[i];
            string s(1,c);
            
            line.append(s); 
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
}
```

The problem is, at the line `char c = code[i];`, the variable stays 0 (checked with gdb). And the program prints gibberish characters every time it runs. I am calling the function like this: `compile("asdf\nasfgh\nafefsfs\n");`. It just prints random 5 characters three times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is your function not returning anthing when it's return value is supposed to be a uint16_t*?

Comment: At least here `while(code[i] != TERMINATOR)`, you should check before that `i` is not greater than the string length

Comment: @Eric i will use it later.

Comment: @Damien i did `if(i > code.length())   break;`, still does not work.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: the `printf` is wrong. You have to call `printf("%s\n", line.c_str())`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik did you read the whole question? I already showed how I called the function.

Comment: Did you read the whole comment? The shown code won't even compile, so how can it be a [mre]?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik well it does compile for me

Comment: @James "i will use it later" - that's not good enough. A function that does not return what it claims to return invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which means your entire program is now invalid and the compiler is under no obligation to generate anything meaningful (and it's also not obligated to tell you about that).

Comment: @JesperJuhl tried with return 0 also

Comment: @Gene now it prints them, but why isn't the variables set while observing with gdb?

Comment: @JamesB.Reese You can copy/paste the code you've posted here, and only that code, and it compiles? What magic compiler do you have?

Comment: Only because your C++ file has other code, in addition to what's shown here. I can guarantee you that nobody will be able to cut/paste what's shown above, put it into a new file, compile it with a C++ compiler, and be able to reproduce the same issue. It won't even compile. For starters, the poor C++ compiler won't have any idea what `uint16_t` or `string` is,

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do I really need to tell what I included? Clearly if I am using uint, and if the question is about string, you need to include `stdint.h`,  `string` and `string.h`. And also i am printing stuff, so `stdio.h`.

Comment: You will improve greatly your chances of getting a helpful answer if you actually do all the work to minimize what anyone else has to do to reproduce your problem. Why should anyone bother to take their time to figure out an answer to a question if nobody even bothered to take their time to write a complete question, read the instructions for [ask] questions on stackoverflow.com, and follow the requirements for a [mre]? I'd rather spend my time helping other people who did do all of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that your `string` is `std::string` and your `printf` is the C standard library's `printf`, there is no automatic conversion applied to the variadic arguments of `printf()`, so your `printf("%s\n", line)` produces undefined behavior on account of the second argument not being correctly type matched to a `%s` directive.  You need to explicitly provide a pointer to a C string there, so

```
printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
```

When I make that change and wrap up your code in a complete program, it produces the output I presume you were expecting:

```
asdf
asfgh
afefsfs
```

Comment: Now it prints them, but why isn't the variables set while observing with gdb?

Comment: Presumably, @JamesB.Reese, because the compiler has optimized that out.  If you're going to examine the program's behavior via `gdb` then you should be sure to compile it with all optimizations disabled, else it is very difficult to interpret what you see.  If you're using a compiler such as `g++` that supports the traditional command-line options, then that would involve using the `-O0` option.  You should provide `-g` as well to get debug info, but the latter does not imply the former.